# Codeigniter white page

Tags: codeigniter

Strange issue: Last night I changed the Arecord and CNAME for a CI site of mine. Now that the changes have propagated and the site runs off a new server, domain.com just gives a blank page. There is nothing in the CI logs (level set to 3). Even a die('test') in the CI root index.php does not appear.

But, domain.com/index.php shows the homepage just fine and all other pages run ok too. On those pages, index.php is not req'd in the url

My htaccess (doubt this is the problem)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Could it be some kind of DNS issue? When I do a ping of domain.com I get 100% packet loss.

```
--- domain.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

Comment: Can you reach the site by it's IP (if you know it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - the problem was caused by a blank index.html file in the root. Hopefully this will help someone one day.